# CFWheels Error: Element RETURNVALUE is undefined in LOC

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have a legacy site using CFWheels v. 1.3.3
It's hosted using ColdFusion 2018.
I haven't changed anything on the site for a couple of years and all appeared to be working fine until recently when I got this error:

> Error Occurred While Processing Request
> Element RETURNVALUE is undefined in LOC.

The error occurred in D:/home/mysite.com/wwwroot/wheels/events/onerror.cfm: line 19

````
18 :    <cfoutput>
19 :        #loc.returnValue#
20 :    </cfoutput>
21 : </cffunction>```

Here's the stack trace:
Stack Trace
at cfonerror2ecfm930916195$funcONERROR.runFunction(D:/home/mysite.com/wwwroot/wheels/events/onerror.cfm:19)

coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedElementException: Element RETURNVALUE is undefined in LOC.
    at coldfusion.runtime.DotResolver.resolveSplitNameInMap(DotResolver.java:185)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolve(CfJspPage.java:2362)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolveAndAutoscalarize(CfJspPage.java:2685)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolveAndAutoscalarize(CfJspPage.java:2675)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._resolveAndAutoscalarize(CfJspPage.java:2655)
    at cfonerror2ecfm930916195$funcONERROR.runFunction(D:\home\mysite.com\wwwroot\wheels\events\onerror.cfm:19)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:553)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:484)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:447)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:398)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:371)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:287)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:830)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:613)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:438)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:115)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onError(AppEventInvoker.java:524)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:647)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:43)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:162)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:96)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:226)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:451)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
````

Comment: Have you output / dumped the value of `loc` in that function to see its value? What defined that variable? Need a lot more info here.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the host of the site had made the public images folder unreadable and that was causing the problem. I thought I would post the solution in case anyone else experiences this problem.

Comment: Yeah wheels can do some weird errors if underlying things change. FWIW I've never had it just break on it's own, something else gets in the way and if a reload of the application doesn't fix it, then something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

`loc` is an object and the code expects it will have a property named `returnValue`. The error is stating that the property with the name `returnValue` doesn't exist on the object.

Looking into the `/wheels/events/onerror.cfm` and then back to the `/wheels/global/cfml.cfm` file where `$simpleLock` is defined tells me there may be some underlying problem with configuration. Hard to nail it down. Safest bet is to restart the application. Generally done through URL parameters. If you can't figure that out, maybe just restart the ColdFusion instance and hope it fixes it.

At the end, ColdFusion is having a hard time invoking a component, but hard to tell which one without more error output.